# PHP cURL detect as bot when run on web server

Tags: php, curl

I use the PHP cURL code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46834320/12616388. When I run the script on localhost I get the desired output. If I run it from my web server, I retrieve a captcha to verify that I am not a bot. I am new to this topic and would like to know the cause. My code:

```
$request = array();
//$request[] = 'host:www.amazon.com';
$request[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$request[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$request[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$request[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$request[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0';//Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36';
$request[] = 'DNT: 1';
$request[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$request[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8';

$url = 'https://www.amazon.de/Wenn-Dunkeln-Sterne-funkeln-Puste-Licht-Buch/dp/3480236529/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=buch&qid=1670662644&sr=8-3';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

EDIT:
I slightly modified the code (random user agent string and multiple cURL requests in a loop) but the problems are the same: on localhost no problems on the webserver I get the captchas).

```
$user_agents = array('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    $request = array();
    $request[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $request[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $request[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
    $request[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
    $request[] = 'User-Agent: ' . $user_agents[array_rand($user_agents)];
    $request[] = 'DNT: 1';
    $request[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
    $request[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8';
    $url = $value['url'];
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You tried passing a cookie to it?

Comment: Awesome! Let me add an answer so you mark it as correct. That way it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only gets triggered when you're on the server, the captcha probably tracks IP addresses. Any chance it's a Recaptcha?

Whatever the captcha is, one thing that could help is solving the captcha from the webserver's IP address.

If the webserver has a desktop environment, connect via VNC (or whatever you ususally use for connecting), open a browser and solve the captcha.

If it does not, try setting up a VPN server on the webserver ([this one](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn) seems easy enough), connect to the VPN from your computer (and thus get the same IP address as your webserver), open a browser and solve the captcha.

Another option is creating a proxy server which will achieve similar result to VPN.

Sadly you'll have to do it from time to time because that's exactly what captcha is for - preventing automated scrapping of websites via bots.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can try to include additional headers or cookies in your cURL request to make it appear more like a real user. For example, you could include the User-Agent header to specify the browser and operating system that your cURL request is coming from, and also you could include the `Cookie` header to include cookies that are typically sent by a real user.

For example:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Include additional headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
  'Cookie: __cfduid=<cookie-data-goes-here>'
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```